# Would placing my usedrange into an array speed up the transfer of this data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large amount of files I'm placing from a dir to a centralized workbook. I store the worksheet names into an array `varWsName` and have some `Case` statements to skip over some steps until later. It works as it should, but I know that the `Copy` method takes up probably more time than creating an array.

Currently I have this:

```
                With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Cells(1, 1)
                End With
```

my question is: if I swapped out `.UsedRange.Copy` with something like:

```
Dim varUsedRange as variant

varUsedRange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value

With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    varUsedRange = wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Range("A1")
End With
```

would this make a difference? I know that's probably not usable syntax, but the general idea is there. Thoughts?

Comment: value transfers (`Range.Value = Range.Value`) are quicker and easier to implement. Could try that and see if it the time gains are sufficient

Comment: You will need to flip the assignation.  currently you would overwrite values in the array from the usedrange with the value in Range `A1`.  Also you will need to create a range the same size as the used range array into which you are assigning the values

Comment: @urdearboy so: `varUsedRange.value = wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Range("A1").value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
Dim varUsedRange As Variant

varUsedRange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varUsedRange, 1), UBound(varUsedRange, 2)).Value = varUsedRange
```

you need the left side to be the target and the right to be the source.

They also must be the same size, hence the `Resize()`

Answer (score 0):

See below.

```
varUsedRange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varUsedRange, 1), UBound(varUsedRange, 2)) = varUsedRange
```